# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ of index $p$ and $pq$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-modules

**Problem:** Suppose $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers. How many subgroups of index $p$ are there in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$? And how many subgroups of index $pq$ are there in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

**Attempt:** I noted that $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}p < \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \mathrel{/} \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}p=\mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus I would like to answer the first question with $2$ but I actually feel that it is wrong. Any help?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528040/subgroups-of-index-p-in-additive-group-mathbbz2). It answers this even for groups of arbitrary index $n$: "More generally, the number of subgroups of index $n$ is $\sigma_1(n) = \sum_{d | n} d$."